# How to suppress stdout warning messages in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When trying to make an API call in Python using requests module, I get a warning message printed to stdout due to verify being set to false. I'm looking for how to suppress these warning messages from printing to stdout. I have already tried to implement urllib3.disable_warnings() function to accomplish this, but with no luck. Any pointers are appriciated.

```
import urllib3
import requests

HOSTNAME = "https://website.example.com"
ADMIN = "admin"
PW = "password"

class ApiCall(object):

    def __init__(self, username=ADMIN, password=PW, url=HOSTNAME, ssl_warnings=False, ssl_verify=False):

    # disable SSL warnings by default
    if not ssl_warnings:
        urllib3.disable_warnings()

    # create requests token to be used across the program
    self.client = requests.Session()
    self.client.auth = (username, password)
    self.client.verify = ssl_verify

def search(self, call=None, name=None):

    ret = self.client.get(HOSTNAME + call)
```

Comment: Does `requests` package it's own `urllib3` - `requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()`?

Comment: I have added this into my code, but I believe I using in the wrong context, I'm looking for into this and how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

As an aditional way of doing it, you can make a context manager to redirect stdout in some context:

For example im gonna redirect `stdout` to `stderror`

```
import contextlib
import sys
@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirectOut():
    sout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr
    yield
    sys.stdout = sout
```

Then you can use it with `with`:

```
with redirectOut():
    #do your stuff here
```

All inside that context will print out to stderr